# How should I migrate an existing Leaflet script to upload kml files to run in React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I would like to know how I can migrate the javascript code (plugin) below to run in React. It allows uploading kml files to leaflet running in html but not work in React-Leaflet

https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-filelayer

I'm already using a version of Leaflet for React but it doesn't have an object that allows the upload of kml files on maps...

Thanks for some guidance

Comment: Please share what you try, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a guidance to ask a question more conform to this site... And the users will help you exactly where you've got issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom component where you will load leaflet file layer library after installing and importing it along with `togeojson` library.

Therefore install and import the two libraries

```
import togeojson from 'togeojson'
import fileLayer from 'leaflet-filelayer'
```

call `fileLayer(null, L, togeojson)` to be able to use `L.Control.fileLayerLoad` ([Source](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.FileLayer/issues/60))

Then create the component as you see it on the official library and place the logic under a useEffect

```
...imports

fileLayer(null, L, togeojson);
...

export default function LeafletFileLayer() {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    const control = L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
      fitBounds: true,
      layerOptions: {
        style: style,
        pointToLayer: function (data, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, { style: style });
        }
      }
    });
    control.addTo(map);
    control.loader.on("data:loaded", function (e) {
      var layer = e.layer;
      console.log(layer);
    });
  }, [map]);

  return null;
}
```

Use it like this

```
 <MapContainer ...>
    ...
    <LeafletFileLayer />
 </MapContainer>
```

I uploaded on the sandbox a geojson from the official leaflet site and a kml to be able to test it. You have to download them first.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-integrate-leafletfilelayer-with-react-leaflet-v-3-x-lgm1x?file=/bus.json)

Comment: Thank you very much @kboul! Worked perfectly! You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[react-leaflet-kml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-kml) is another option for getting KML, using react-leaflet, with a working example included in the link.

I can confirm it works well, however it lacks documentation or advanced features.